# UPDATE every column start with special letter

Tags: mysql

I have about 30 table witch all of them have almost same names like 
"pro1" , "pro2" , "pro3" , ..... , "pro30"
and my tables have columns named
"L0" "R0" "L1" "R1" "L2" "R2" .......... "L99" "R99"

I want to update every column that start with letter "R" and reduce its value by one

I don't know how to achieve this with MySQL code since I want to use it as an event scheduler.

this is what i have
UPDATE test SET R0 = IF (R0>0,R0-1,0),R1 = IF (R1>0,R1-1,0),R2 = IF (R2>0,R2-1,0), ...........

Comment: let us step back. Why do you have this table structure

Comment: I also tried     UPDATE test SET LIKE R% = IF (R%>0,R%-1,0)

Comment: was that an answer to my comment question

Comment: No, it wasn't. I actually write that after my main text.

Comment: The L stands for learn, and the R stands for review. If  the R0 column hold value of 0 it means it's time for review. I actually can change my table structure and put them in two different row (I mean L row and R row), but I wonder if I could achieve this without changing my other codes related to this tables. If there is a way please help me, and if not I will change my structure. thanks.

Comment: it is possible. One way is to read the table structure from the table. `show columns from people;`  That comes back as a result set. Grab all the columns you want, and construct an update statement into a string, and just query that. Or have it embedded inside of a `Create Event`

Comment: But frankly, I would just bite the bullet and start typing it out. You say most of your tables are the same.

Comment: Thanks Drew. I have a problem with mysql. why we can change all the fields in one column easily, like this `UPDATE test SET score = 0` and every field under this column will be effected. but we can not do the same thing with a single row. why we cant do something like `UPDATE test SET EVERY FIELDS = 0 WHERE id=10`. I studied almost all the pages of the w3schools.com  SQL Tutorial but I couldn't find something helpful about my problem. thanks again Drew.

Comment: I believe it is because dbs arent spreadsheets with row numbers. They have structure not chaos

Comment: So there really is no easy way to achieve this, Okay, thank you Drew.

Comment: Quick question. do you think spreadsheets are chaos? are they that bad?

Comment: I think spreadsheets *can* be non-chaotic. I know a lot of db developers that would say "I cannot believe this org is using a spreadsheet for this" from time to time. In fact I don't know of any that haven't said that. Us developers (you included) suffer from Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde complexes from time to time, wanting to jump back and forth between the two worlds